# Can't insert values into a database

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm trying to get some data of a website and store it in a database but it's not working and I don't know what's the error. Can you help me?

Error:

```
Error syntax error at or near "INTEGER"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE test(id SERIAL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_date ...
```

Code (the website chosen was just a test):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2
import sys

page = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wushu_at_the_2014_Asian_Games_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_sanda_60_kg")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable")

A = [] 
B = []
C = []

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("th")
    if len(cells) != 0:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))

con = None
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("host= 'localhost' dbname='testdb' user='postgres' password='root'")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test(id SERIAL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_date TEXT, event_time VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)" % A, B, C)
    con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    if con:
        con.rollback()
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: remove the `integer` after `serial`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `SERIAL INTEGER`:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, event_date TEXT, event_time VARCHAR)
```

> I don't know what's the error

What do you mean? I tried just the `try` block, and it gave a clear error message on this problem. Maybe the preceding code has other errors that kill the program.

Your INSERT also seems to have a problem. Why not `CREATE` the table first and call `INSERT` in the loop on `table.findAll` ?

Comment: You were right about that but, I still get an error on the interpreter says it's here:     cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)" % A, B, C)

Comment: Yes, you cannot give a list as argument and that it would expand to insert multiple rows. That means you're trying to insert a single row with field types of array. Either loop on A and run `INSERT` in that loop, or move `INSERT` inside the previous loop. Also, a `%s` is needed for each field to be `INSERT`ed

Comment: I put the code like this: https://pastebin.com/uB8B7gfb but now i have this error: not enough arguments for format string (it's on the same line)

Comment: Your `con.close` is before the loop where you `INSERT`?
The idea was that when `INSERT` is inside loop, you don't need lists A, B and C. Just use normal variables for current row only. Forget those `Append()` s
And the error is because `A, B, C` should be `(A, B, C)`, just remember they can't be lists!
Did you read any documentation of psycopg?

Comment: I saw a tutorial. I need to put lists because it's a table that i want to get don't i? So, i have to put the con.close on the end and delete the lists and appends and then what?